# Prettier way to write this script (Hide span on click, show input)

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code:

```
$('body').on('click', 'span.note', function (event) {
    $(this).hide();
    $(".addnote").show();
});
$('body').on('focusout', '.addnote', function (event) {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        $(this).hide();
        $("span.note").show();
    }
});
```

And this is my HTML:

```
     <span class="note">test</span>
     <input class="addnote" type="text" style="display:none;">
```

What it does is: on click it hides the span and displays the input field and when leaving the input field empty and on `focusout` it returns the span.

It works but I'm pretty sure there is a prettier way to write this. Can anyone assist me and point out what I could improve. Thanks.

EDIT: Also, i noticed when clicking the text the Input shows but i have to click it again to be able to write, any way to fix so with 1 click it displays the field and the visitor can type in the field?

Comment: Your code is not working

Comment: you need to add setfocus Check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/L6Hjc/

Comment: Insted of using class selecter use id, as class selector are the slowest among the all

Comment: @RohitTiwari the question is too general to state that. If the structure is duplicated in the same page, ID aren't a solution either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the elements are siblings you can also pass an object to the `.on()` method:

```
$('body').on({
    click: function() {
       $(this).filter('span').hide().next().show();
    },
    blur: function() {
       this.value == '' && $(this).hide().prev().show();  
    }
}, 'span.note, .addnote');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/27kYh/

Comment: An object containing multiple handlers to `.on()`. This is very cool. +1

Answer (score 2):

To let the user type immediatly, you only need to set focus to the input element after showing it:

```
$(".addnote").show().focus();
```

In my opinion, there's not that much improving that could be done on this piece of code. By itself, it's not badly written. The only thing is, this won't work if you add multiple such controls on the same page, because your selectors aren't specific enough.

You could change:

```
if ($(this).val() == "") {
```

to

```
if (!$(this).val()) {
```

if you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if its prettier, but you can make it a little shorter, if your HTML structure is as in your question.

```
$('body')
    .on('click', 'span.note', function () {
        $(this).hide().next('.addnote').show();
    })
    .on('focusout', '.addnote', function () {
        if(!this.value) $(this).hide().prev('.note').show();
    });
```

Comment: I like your approach with the `on()` method chaining. But the contents of the closures are not really readable. It's shorter but not really readable.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the shortest one (almost everything is chained)

```
$('span.note').click(function() {
    $(this).hide().next().blur( function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "") $(this).hide().prev().show();
   }).show();
});
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/BcLUR/)

Answer (score 1):

You can user `.toggle()` property for this,

and call `span click event` on `focusout` of `addnote`.

```
$('body').on('click', 'span.note', function (event) {
    $(this).toggle();
    $(".addnote").toggle();
});

$('body').on('focusout', '.addnote', function (event) {
    if (!$(this).val()) {
        $( "span.note" ).trigger( "click" );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could clean up your selector a little?

```
$('.note').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $(".addnote").show();
});
$('.addnote').focusout(function(){
    if (!$(this).val()) {
        $(this).hide();
        $("span.note").show();
    }
});
```

Not sure if this is what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').on('click', 'span.note', function (event) {
    $(this).hide();
    $(".addnote").show().focus();//add focus when element is shown
});
$('body').on('focusout', '.addnote', function (event) {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        $(this).hide();
        $("span.note").show();
    }
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6bCaJ/)

Answer (score 1):

Write a function for this purpose, like as below

```
function cal(e){
    var t= e;
    $('*').show();
    $(e).hide();
}
$('body').on('click', '.note', function (event) {
    cal($(this));
});

$('body').on('focusout', '.addnote', function (event) {
    if($(this).val()=='')
    cal($(this));
});
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mHNL8/1/)